# Tag bug involving auto-chopping of excess words in wiki excerpts

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

The Tags page, when showing excerpts, automatically removes some key words from the beginning of excerpts (e.g. "Terminal is" from [terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminal)). This mostly works fine, except for two things:

- **Capitalization inconsistency**

  It does not then capitalize the first remaining word, so some excerpts begin with "the" and some "The."
- **Extra deleted text**

  At least one tag ([backup](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backup)) has extra text removed. See the below screenshots.

Text displayed on the Tags page:

[image: summary on the tag page]

Text displayed upon hover:

[image: hovertext]

Comment: Are you OK with the answer provided? Would you like us to move this to the main meta site since that's where consensus would need to be built to change the system wide design.

Answer (score 1):

This is an intentional feature and not simply a bug.

The reasons for it are enumerated here (as well as the regex used to neuter presumably excessively wordy tag summaries):

- [New tags page mangles tag wiki excerpts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82700/new-tags-page-mangles-tag-wiki-excerpts)

In summary, this looks like a design compromise to fit a portion of the text within the available space.

Comment: That's a bizarre algorithm. It it's intentional, someone has odd intentions. I see what they're trying to do, but I believe they're doing it wrong.

Comment: @DanielLawson We can take it up on the [main meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) if you want to see if it could be changed...